# Mean absolute percentage error returning NAN in PyTorch

Tags: lstm, recurrent-neural-network, percentage, mape

I'm using [mean absolute percentage error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_absolute_percentage_error) (MAPE) as a loss function for an RNN, however during training I start getting NaN values. I first used MAPE to calculate error between sequences of 3D coordinates, and while the values were incredibly high, they weren't NaN. I then tried using MAPE to calculate the error for the deltas of the coordinates (the differences between each pair of coordinate sets). It was during this point that I started getting NaN values for loss.

I also used [relative percent difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_change_and_difference) (RPD), which sometimes gives a NaN for loss when calculating on the deltas. Here is the code I wrote to implement MAPE and RPD (for both the coordinates and their deltas/diffs):

```
def MAPELoss(output, target):
  return torch.mean(torch.abs((target - output) / target))    

def RPDLoss(output, target):
  return torch.mean(torch.abs(target - output) / ((torch.abs(target) + torch.abs(output)) / 2))    

def MAPELoss_Diff(output, target):
  output = output[1:] - output[:-1]
  target = target[1:] - target[:-1]
  return torch.mean(torch.abs((target - output) / target))    

def RPDLoss_Diff(output, target):
  output = output[1:] - output[:-1]
  target = target[1:] - target[:-1]
  return torch.mean(torch.abs(target - output) / ((torch.abs(target) + torch.abs(output)) / 2))
```

Looking at the above code, I don't see why the loss functions for diff lead to NaN values (rarely for RPD but MAPE converges to NaN quickly). I printed inside the functions and it seems that the NaN values come from the output parameter, meaning my model is starting to predict NaN during training. When I initially looked this up, a common reason was exploding gradients but I'm not sure why this loss function would lead to that.

As for why I'm using MAPE and RPD in the first place, the coordinates are normalized to a 1x1x1 bounding box, so all their values will be <1. Doing traditional loss functions like MSE will lead to <1 values being squared, so the model will think it has a really low loss when it's actually performing badly. Especially so when calculating loss on the deltas as those will be very small. If there are other methods entirely I should be using for this, I'd love to hear them (I'm very new to this).

For context, I'm trying to make a sequence to sequence LSTM model to predict human pose (a series of 3D coordinates). I need the poses to move to show motion, hence why I figured trying to calculate loss on the pose deltas.

Comment: add epsilon to denominators?

Comment: If you are predicting 3d coordinates, aren't you dividing by 3d vectors? That would not be defined mathematically. Also: [What are the shortcomings of the Mean Absolute Percentage Error (MAPE)?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/299712/1352)

Comment: @S.Kolassa-ReinstateMonica Why would 3D vectors / 3D vectors be undefined? Or perhaps I'm misunderstanding how the division works, I was under the assumption that it would be an element wise operation, i.e. [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]] / [[4,5,6], [1,2,3]] = [[1/4, 2/5, 3/6], [4/1, 5/2, 6/3]] etc.

Comment: You can do that elementwise. I suspect your errors come from some almost-zero actual coordinates.

Comment: @S.Kolassa-ReinstateMonica Yeah, since the bounding box is 1x1x1 some of the coordinates are like 6.4354e-5 etc. Do you think scaling the coordinates before loss calculation could alleviate this? i.e. (target*1000 - output*1000) / (target*1000), where / is doing element wise division?

Comment: Why use percentage errors at all? is a delta of 0.01 really less of a problem if the underlying actual is near 1 rather than near 0? Bounding boxes are arbitrary, anyway - you could shift them around, or even rotate them. For graphical analyses, I'd go with something like the Euclidean distance between the prediction and the actual.

Comment: @S.Kolassa-ReinstateMonica I feel really stupid that I didn't think of Euclidean distance first considering I'm dealing with 3D coordinates. To answer why percentage, I needed something to train my RNN on that wouldn't be affected by the scale of the values, since it just tries to push error down (with small values it will think error is small and that it is already performing well). To that point, the same issue applies even with Euclidean distance (distance of small coordinates will be small) so am I correct in that I have to scale the values?